# LINQ ANY() with First() And FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I've written  code like this

```
TotalCashIn = totals != null && totals.Any() ? totals.First().TotalCashIn : null;
```

And i have been blamed for this code and have told to write like this

```
TotalCashIn = totals != null ? totals.FirstOrDefault().TotalCashIn : null;
```

But I am wondering would not I get an exception if **totals** count would be 0?
 Do I need also check  this with `.Any()` or `.Count()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) to make all of this a lot simpler, assuming that the element type of `totals` is a reference type:

```
TotalCashIn = totals?.FirstOrDefault()?.TotalCashIn;
```

With this:

- If `totals` is null, the overall result is null due to the first null-conditonal operator
- If `totals` is empty, `FirstOrDefault()` will return null, so the overall result is null due to the second null-conditional operator
- Otherwise, the result is the `TotalCashIn` property of the first element

Comment: If the element types of totals are  `decimal?` would above code work ?

Comment: @So_oP: Yes, that should be absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether `totals` is `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`. If it is `IQueryable` then you can also use following:

```
TotalCashIn = totals?.Select(t => (int?)t.TotalCashIn).FirstOrDefault();
```

It would be better as you select only desired field and not all columns in a table.

Answer (score 0):

If totals is a reference type object, then indeed, FirstOrDefault might return null, and thus you can't call TotalCashIn.

If on the other hand totals is a value type, then FirstOrDefault would return an actual value and you could call TotalCashIn. For instance if totals would be a sequence of integers, then FirstOrDefault would return zero (not null!).

If TotalCashIn would be an extension function of int, then if would be perfect to call TotalCashIn after FirstOrDefault:

```
IEnumerable<int> totals = ...
int firstInt = totals.FirstOrDefault();
var totalCashIn = firstInt.TotalCashIn(); // extension function of int
```

or in one statement:

```
var totalCashIn = totals.FirstOrDefault().TotalCashIn();
```

Whether it is wise to use the null-conditional operator (?.) depends on the definition of your TotalCashIn, especially if your collection has no element at all.

If you'd say: "TotalCashIn represents the amount of money I cashed while ...", then TotalCashIn could have a zero value, but not a null value.

If you want a zero value in case of empty collections, consider to use Select to select the property you want before your FirstOrDefault:

```
var totalCashIn = totals.Select(item => item.TotalCashIn).FirstOrDefault();
```

If property TotalCashIn is a value type then this will return zero if your totals collection is empty

Upon your question whether to use Count() or Any(): never use Count() to test if your sequence has any elements unless you are certain the your input sequence is an ICollection. It is really a waste of computing power to access all elements of your sequence if after the first element you would already know there are elements.

Comment: totals is a single row and values are decimal? types.also totals  is Iqueryable

Comment: fails in case of `totals == null`

Comment: You are right. Therefore you should never wise to let an IEnumerable have a null value if you want to indicate that there are no elements in the collection. In such cases, let the "creator" or the IEnumerable return `Enumerable.Empty<myclass>()` instead of null

Comment: `TotalCashIn` must be a reference type, otherwise the original code won't compile.

Comment: @mjwills: Or a nullable value type.

Comment: Correct @JonSkeet - in which case `null` will be returned. Either way, `FirstOrDefault` will definitely be returning `null` - there is no need to worry it will return 0 etc.

Comment: mjwillis: are you sure Totals is not a sequence of integers and TotalCashIn an extension method of int?

Comment: If it was a method, wouldn't it be `TotalCashIn()` rather than `TotalCashIn`?

Comment: Ok, you are right. But this only expands usability of the answer: you can use the answer even if the type was a value type, and even if the function was an extension function. No need to ask a new question if the only difference are the parentheses after the property identifier. The answer also works in such cases

Comment: TotalCashIn  is a value form the totals not an extension method.